# Get JSON Key values using GSON library

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I am trying to get the JSON Object from my form.

Please find the JSON Below:

```
[{"id":["4"]},{"Flap":["NA"]}]
```

So I am using a hidden attribute to save the value into a JsonObject (from Gson library) in my ModelForm. When I call this object from my controller, I am not able to get the values by key.

In jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myForm" action="/action">
<input type="hidden" name="jsonObject" id="jsonObj" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function getjson()"/>
</form:form>
```

In js I am collecting all checked boxes and saving the information in the form of Json on submitting the value.

In JS:

```
function getjson(){
    var json = [];
    var checkedBoxes = $('input[name="checkedList"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
var checkedBoxes1 = $('input[name="checkedList1"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    json.push({"id":checkedBoxes});
    json.push({"Flap":checkedBoxes1});
    document.getElementById("jsonObj").value = json;
}
```

In MyForm.Java:

```
private JsonObject jsonObjct;
//getters and setters for jsonObjct
```

I am collecting the information of the checked values in the form of json and saving it in "jsonObjct" in MyForm and trying to retrieve the value in my controller using:

```
myForm.getJsonObjct();
```

Can anyone please help me out with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code?

Comment: Hi @Coder i have added the code. Sorry for not being clear previously.

Comment: how is the JSON sent to java object `MyForm` ? what's the format you are sending in ?

Comment: @Coder it would be in this format. [{"id":["4"]},{"Flap":["NA"]}].  

I dont know if it is saving in jsonObjct but i am not able to use the value in controller.

Comment: By format I mean how is it passed to java object at all? Your code doesn't show any aspect which is setting the data to object

Comment: @Coder its a part of form data. I have edited the post.

Comment: Maybe I am unclear on what I am asking. I was looking for the part of the code where you are serializing this form data to construct the java objects

Comment: Its a Spring MVC application where the binding will be taken by Spring.

Comment: So I am trying here to save the jsonValue in a form and use the value in the controller. I tried many different ways but nothing worked. :(

Comment: Now I got the an overall idea but it is hard to pin point the root cause as it might be anything that is going wrong

Comment: I think its not even setting the value in jsonObct. @Coder. Do you have any idea why if it might be the case?

Comment: It's hard to comment without the option of debugging available to me

Comment: The name of variable is not matching, you are setting it as "jsonObj" but while fetching you are using with different name "getJsonObjct". Try using getJsonObj()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly this `[{"id":["4"]},{"Flap":["NA"]}]` is a jsonArray. if you can use `org.json` jar that will be better and very simple.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class GsonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString="[{\"id\":[\"4\"]},{\"Flap\":[\"NA\"]}]";
        JSONArray arr= new JSONArray(jsonString);
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("id").get(0));
    }
}
```

The output is 4. i guess that what you need.

Comment: Thank you. :) @boukobba adil